# Restrict Player Movement "Speed" in Java Swing Game

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I've implemented a game where a player can move a sprite around in a tile-based maze. The player controls the sprite with the arrow keys. What I want is to restrict the speed at which the player can move around, e.g. I don't want them to be able to hold down the arrow key and fly across the screen. I tried fixing this by implementing a sleep:

```
switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:    // Up arrow key
            if (running) {
                player.Move(1); // Move North
            }
            paintPlayer(getGraphics());
            // So the player can't hold down the arrow key and fly across the screen, force them to wait between inputs
            // BUT this leads to problems if you do hold it down, moves end up in a 'queue'...
            try {
                Thread.sleep(150);
                break;
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MazeView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            break;
// etc.
```

But this leads to problems if you hold the arrow key down - the moves seem to end up in some kind of "queue" and you end up constantly crashing into a wall until all the moves from your extended key press are done. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You could move the player only for a key pressed or released event

Comment: Yeah, that seems to have done the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously I was doing a keyPressed() event, but as Riyafa suggested, I changed it to only fire on keyReleased(), and that's done it. There's no need to include sleeps anymore either.

Comment: Who told you that you can control the speed with sleep in the event message loop, as the GUI thread is?

Answer (score 0):

I advise to investigate Switng Timer. As the name suggests its action is performed in the same thread as your Key event listener and all other GUI stuff, so you can easily painting there and update game state, based on key/button states. You can also use `swingutilities.invokelater(new runnable()` if you are waiting is some another thread. I did not do Swing for a long time and forgotten everything but I am sure that this is how dynamic games are supposed to be done.